# segmentation fault caused by strsep returning null

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, string-parsing, strsep

I am writing a program in C and I want to count how the number of words in the string by dividing the string by the spaces.

Here is some of my code

```
  while((temp = strsep(&tempInput, " "))!=NULL)
  {
    tempArguments[number] = temp;
    number++;
    printf("AGAIN\n");
  }
  printf("number: %d",number);
```

For some reason I get a segmentation fault when the loop terminates. Does anybody have an idea as to what could be causing this?

Comment: I think the most important bits here are going to be how `number`, `tempArguments` and `tempInput` are declared and initialized.

Comment: I don't `tempInput` is the problem here as I assume you are sending that as a char** buffer pointer.  Maybe your `tempArguments` array is going out of bounds.

Comment: the tempArguments array is of size 80, arbitrarily chosen, and in this case there is one string being put into it.